# Add lines to a file without overwriting google-drive sdk

Tags: google-drive-api

In the Google-Drive developers guide they show us to:

i) upload a file:
https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads

ii) update a file's data:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update

The second option ii) update a file data by overwriting the file's previous data. Is there anyway I can add data to a file without overwriting it? Just add lines to a file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No

The Drive API deals with files as a whole.